# How to insert a string in SQLite database without conversion?

Tags: string, sqlite, behavior

The table:
CREATE TABLE configuration(Key STRING, Value STRING, PRIMARY KEY (Key) );

Here is what I tried:
insert into configuration(Key,Value) values(42,cast('0042' as text));

Here is the dump:
INSERT INTO "configuration" VALUES(42,42);

What I wanted:
INSERT INTO "configuration" VALUES(42,'0042');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the table with:

```
CREATE TABLE configuration(Key STRING, Value TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (Key) );
```

(there is no storage penalty for doing this with SQLite) then you'll get the leading zeroes preserved, even if you use the very simplest form of INSERT. This is because [`STRING` is not a real SQLite type, and so has `NUMERIC` affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

Comment: Not for SQLite. `STRING` will be interpreted to `TEXT`. So would `VARCHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, and `POTATO`. (I kid you not).

Comment: @MPelletier: I know that, but I also know that when I use `TEXT` it works and when I use `STRING` it doesn't. I simply tested it.

Comment: @MPelletier: Hah. It's *documented* that STRING is NUMERIC (see edited-in link). That's a real nasty gotcha!

Comment: Nice! I hadn't picked up on that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying, but essentially, it should be:

```
INSERT INTO configuration VALUES(42,'0042');
```

Comment: Sorry, configuration should not be between quotes.

Comment: That makes no difference. (The quotes were fine; that's SQL syntax for a named entity such as column or field where the name can't be used “bare”.) Really. I just type this into an interactive session and get the wrong behavior…